# User gestures and back button are not working when using PageRouteBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

to achieve a fade transition I used a `PageRouteBuilder()`to build some of my routes.
I noticed however while testing the app that the back button on Android and The User gesture on IOS are not working to navigate back to previous route!

Is this the normal behavior of the `PageRouteBuilder()`? or am I maybe doing something wrong?

thanks a lot!

Comment: where is it navigating back to? is it exiting the app?

Comment: Can you post some code for that ??

Answer (score 2):

So as it turned out, in `MaterialPageRoute()` the `PageTransitionBuilder` is selected based on which platform the app is running on.

I was able to get it to work for Android by using the `WillPopScope()` widget, as I was using Nested Navigators.

However, on IOS for the back gesture they are using the private class `_CupertinoBackGestureController` and I don't think there is an easy way to achieve that at this moment!

Hope that helps whoever is facing the same thing and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The popup to back button has nothing to do with PageRouteBuilder, but has something to do with how you are inserting the second page in the stack.

If you are using `Navigator.pushNamed(context, <PageRouteBuilder>)`, this will keep the first page in the stack and the back button should work.
However, If you are using `Navigator.pushNamedReplacement(context, <PageRouteBuilder>)`, it will remove the first page and push the second page to stack.

Comment: But on pressing back button, it should go some where right ?? even if the page is not pushed using the right push method, it should atleast close the app, right ??

Comment: you could try Navigator.pop() to check if the first screen is still in the stack.. override the back button with Navigator.pop()

Comment: I am actually using the `Navigator.pushNamed(context, <PageRouteBuilder>)` and `fullscreenDialog` is set to `false`. that's why I thought it was weird!

Comment: Pressing the back button is closing the app. And It's also working as expected when using `MaterialPageRoute`

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently experimenting with wrapping the page to be pushed in a GestureDetector, and then setting one of the onHorizontalDrag properties to pop the route. (I do this within the PageRouteBuilder itself, that way I can just pass in the page like normal when pushing.) This [swipedetector package](https://pub.dev/packages/swipedetector) might replace the GestureDetector, or I might even experiment with this [swipe_back_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_back_detector/example) specifically made for custom routes made with PageRouteBuilder (see example they give).